# Отправка координат телефона в Firebase

Tags: android, service, firebase, android-location, locationmanager

Ребята , помогите начинающему программисту , хотел в качестве обучения написать сервис на андроид который будет отсылать каждую минуту в firebase database координаты телефона , если с координатами и бд  разобраться не сложно , то обьясните пожалуйста как организовать сам сервис чтобы каждую минуту он выполнял код получения координат и их отправление в firebase , направьте просто в нужном направлении , опишите как лучше нужно реализовать такую затею .

Comment: Сервис + Retrofit

Comment: да как отправлять данные не проблема , меня больше интересует то как организовать сервис который будет запускаться каждую минуту и выполнять код, или может это как то по другому делается , я не совсем знаком еще с сервисами , и мне не понятно как организовать такое , какие классы и методы использовать для этого